# Terraform Init from Github Actions

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I'm trying to call terraform init from Github actions. I'm using the Google provider which includes the block:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("cred.json")
  project     = var.project
  region      = var.region
  zone        = var.zone
}
```

When I run this locally, its fine because the creds.json (service account key json) is there, but I don't want to have that key checked out as part of the repo in GHA. Instead the json for the key is added as a secret: ${{ env.GCP_CREDENTIALS }}

How do I get Terraform to use that secret in the 'terraform init' command?
I tried changing the line to:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = ${{ env.GCP_CREDENTIALS }}
  project     = var.project
  region      = var.region
  zone        = var.zone
}
```

But it just errors out. There must be a simpler way?

Comment: I don't know if the env variable can be used that way. Wouldn't it be easier to create the `cred.json` in the pipeline from the secret before performing the `terraform init` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variable must point to a file which is the location for a service account JSON key. You could write the contents to an artifact, but that is dangerous. . Still, a simple workaround to this would be:

If you want to place your credentials in a Terraform Cloud environment variable:

- Create an environment variable called GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS in your Terraform Cloud workspace.
- Remove the newline characters from your JSON key file and then paste the credentials into the environment variable value field. You can use the tr command to strip newline characters. `cat key.json | tr -s '\n' ' '`
- Mark the variable as Sensitive and click Save variable.

Alternative:

You can use this GitHub action to log in. Pretty much you have to create a secret with the content of the service account and specified it as input:

```
- id: 'auth'
  name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
  uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
  with:
    credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}
```

Comment: The light came on when I read your answer. I had stupidly included what I thought was the google login just before the terraform init, but on looking at your code sample I realised it was actually just the gcloud login I was using. D'oh! When I precede the terraform actions with the proper gcp login block - it works great and you don't even need to include the credentials field in the provider block. Thanks!